# dump entire bigmap as key/value pairs

Tags: bigmap

How to dump entire bigmap as key/value pairs?

Taquito "promises" [Fetch multiple big map values at once](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/maps_bigmaps/#fetch-multiple-big-map-values-at-once) but in reality multiple RPC calls are made.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with TzKT API: https://api.tzkt.io/#operation/BigMaps_GetKeys. However, if there are more than 10k keys, you will still have to do multiple requests (i.e. paginate), because the max limit in TzKT is 10k items per request.

For example, https://api.tzkt.io/v1/bigmaps/9563/keys?active=true&select=key,value&limit=10000